# ROS (Melodic) + Docker: rosrun not found

Tags: ros-melodic, docker, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am currently trying to run ROS Melodic on Docker to build the rosserial_arduino libraries for Arduino. Therefore I need to run
`rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py` in the Docker container. However I get a `rosrun: command not found`, despite sourcing the `setup.bash`. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full-bionic as builder_base
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ros-melodic-rosserial-arduino \
    ros-melodic-rosserial \
    python-rosdep \
    python-rosinstall \
    python-rosinstall-generator \
    python-wstool \
    build-essential \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/

RUN echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN source ~/.bashrc
WORKDIR /arduino
RUN rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py
```

I run this on Ubuntu 19.04.

Any ideas why I get this error and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350169/ros-(melodic)-+-docker:-rosrun-not-found/) by [Julian98](https://answers.ros.org/users/33845/julian98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2020-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Docker, all `RUN` statements are executed in a separate shell (this is not entirely correct, but it gets the point across). So `source` in one `RUN` statement does not affect the environment in which another is run.

> ```
> RUN source ~/.bashrc
> ```

You can do this, but you'll need to run this in `bash`, otherwise it won't work (something like `bash -c 'source ...'`).

But I believe there is an easier way to do this:

```
RUN /opt/ros/melodic/env.sh rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py
```

The `env.sh` script takes care of loading all the required environment variables.

I would also recommend to use relative paths as little as possible, as they may not resolve to where you expect them to resolve to in Docker builds.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-22**:
PS: technically this isn't really a ROS problem, but caused by the way Docker (builds) work(s).

**Comment by [Julian98](https://answers.ros.org/users/33845/julian98/) on 2020-04-22**:
Thank you very much!
It is indeed, but I think it might be helpful for other people working with ROS to have it answered in this forum.